# Consuming an external api with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, post, controller

I'm not using `get` method but still getting this error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

This is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\api;
use  App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class loginuser extends Controller
{
    public function log()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://132.148.19.159/OAuth/Token');
        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();

        return $body;
    }
}
```

And this is my route:

```
Route::post('login_user', [loginuser::class, 'log']);
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Is it in browser?

Comment: If we asume you are using the right route. Then the cache of the routes might be causing the problem. You may try this `php artisan route:clear` and then `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: I have already done that and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the error you see covers from the Guzzle call? It seems like you are accessing your own loginuser log route using get instead of POST. The error you see comes from Symfony, not Guzzle. Verify your code inside the log function is actually executed.

Comment: I have tested the external api using postman and i get a reponse with the token access, now im trying to consume it using laravel and its not working.i've used httpClient and then Guzzle just to get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, you install the package `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`
then in  your controller :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\api;
use  App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class loginuser extends Controller
{
    public function log()
    {
        $response = Http::post('http://132.148.19.159/OAuth/Token');
        $body = $response->body();
        return $body;
    }
}
```

reference : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client